# Jquery Serialize ONCE on submit

Tags: php, jquery, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I´m very new to jquery and javascript in general and I have this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#sortMe').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
           var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');
           console.log(postData);

           $("#submit").click(function() {
                $.post('save.php', {list: postData}, function(o) {
                console.log(o);
                }, 'json');
           })
        }
    });
});
```

What I want to do is serialize "postData" ONCE when I finish "sorting" the divs, click "submit" and post it to save.php. At the moment, if I "sort" my divs 3 times lets say, before I click "submit", the postData is sent 3 times to save.php.

Here is my index.php

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="sortMe">

        <div id='item_0'>Test 1</div>
        <div id='item_1'>Test 2</div>
        <div id='item_2'>Test 3</div>
        <div id='item_3'>Test 4</div>
        <div id='item_4'>Test 5</div>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit!">

    </div>
    <!-- end of sortMe -->

</div>
<!-- end of wrap -->
```

and my save.php

```
$list = $_POST['list'];

$output = array();
$list = parse_str($list, $output);

$a = implode(',', $output['item']);
```

I'd appreciate any help with this! Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the HTMl code ??

Comment: Hi Sameer K - I´ve now included the html / php. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you  try by moving "submit" function outside of "sortable" function ??

Comment: Thanks Sameer, actually after spending the week doing some heavy learning, i´m starting to understand jquery syntax alot better now! Thanks for your help though!